# Master data together with detail data

Tags: fastreport

I want to print detail lines flanked left and right by various master fields.
Example layout for a master record and its detail records:

```
masterAA    detail line 1     masterBB
masterCC    detail line 2     masterDD
            detail line 3
            detail line 4     masterEE
            detail line 5
            detail line 6
```

(repeated for the next master records)

The master data fields (masterAA to masterEE in the example) must be printed even if there are no detail data for a master record.
The master fields do not necessarily align with the detail fields due to font sizes and line heights of the master fields.

Can this be achieved by settings alone or by programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using a subreport (TfrxSubreport) for printing the detail lines.